# Bootstrap 3 tabs with 100% height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I don't understand why the page doesn't fit the screen and why a scroll bar is added to the page.

Here is the code:

```css
#side {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}

.list {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
 overflow: auto;
}

html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
.fill {
 padding: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}
.container-side {
 padding: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.tablist {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid fill">
 <div class="row-fluid fill">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 container-side">
   <div id="side">
    <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs hidden-print">
     <li class="active"><a href="#tab-1" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#tab-2" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab-1" class="tablist container-fluid tab-pane fade in active">
     <div class="list">
      <p>
      Illud tamen clausos vehementer angebat quod captis navigiis, quae frumenta vehebant per flumen, Isauri quidem alimentorum copiis adfluebant, ipsi vero solitarum rerum cibos iam consumendo inediae propinquantis aerumnas exitialis horrebant.

      Cognitis enim pilatorum caesorumque funeribus nemo deinde ad has stationes appulit navem, sed ut Scironis praerupta letalia declinantes litoribus Cypriis contigui navigabant, quae Isauriae scopulis sunt controversa.

      Alii nullo quaerente vultus severitate adsimulata patrimonia sua in inmensum extollunt, cultorum ut puta feracium multiplicantes annuos fructus, quae a primo ad ultimum solem se abunde iactitant possidere, ignorantes profecto maiores suos, per quos ita magnitudo Romana porrigitur, non divitiis eluxisse sed per bella saevissima, nec opibus nec victu nec indumentorum vilitate gregariis militibus discrepantes opposita cuncta superasse virtute.

      Illud tamen te esse admonitum volo, primum ut qualis es talem te esse omnes existiment ut, quantum a rerum turpitudine abes, tantum te a verborum libertate seiungas; deinde ut ea in alterum ne dicas, quae cum tibi falso responsa sint, erubescas. Quis est enim, cui via ista non pateat, qui isti aetati atque etiam isti dignitati non possit quam velit petulanter, etiamsi sine ulla suspicione, at non sine argumento male dicere? Sed istarum partium culpa est eorum, qui te agere voluerunt; laus pudoris tui, quod ea te invitum dicere videbamus, ingenii, quod ornate politeque dixisti.

     Illud tamen te esse admonitum volo, primum ut qualis es talem te esse omnes existiment ut, quantum a rerum turpitudine abes, tantum te a verborum libertate seiungas; deinde ut ea in alterum ne dicas, quae cum tibi falso responsa sint, erubescas. Quis est enim, cui via ista non pateat, qui isti aetati atque etiam isti dignitati non possit quam velit petulanter, etiamsi sine ulla suspicione, at non sine argumento male dicere? Sed istarum partium culpa est eorum, qui te agere voluerunt; laus pudoris tui, quod ea te invitum dicere videbamus, ingenii, quod ornate politeque dixisti.

     Illud tamen te esse admonitum volo, primum ut qualis es talem te esse omnes existiment ut, quantum a rerum turpitudine abes, tantum te a verborum libertate seiungas; deinde ut ea in alterum ne dicas, quae cum tibi falso responsa sint, erubescas. Quis est enim, cui via ista non pateat, qui isti aetati atque etiam isti dignitati non possit quam velit petulanter, etiamsi sine ulla suspicione, at non sine argumento male dicere? Sed istarum partium culpa est eorum, qui te agere voluerunt; laus pudoris tui, quod ea te invitum dicere videbamus, ingenii, quod ornate politeque dixisti.


      </p>
      <p>
      Illud tamen clausos vehementer angebat quod captis navigiis, quae frumenta vehebant per flumen, Isauri quidem alimentorum copiis adfluebant, ipsi vero solitarum rerum cibos iam consumendo inediae propinquantis aerumnas exitialis horrebant.

      Cognitis enim pilatorum caesorumque funeribus nemo deinde ad has stationes appulit navem, sed ut Scironis praerupta letalia declinantes litoribus Cypriis contigui navigabant, quae Isauriae scopulis sunt controversa.
      </p>
      <p>
      Illud tamen clausos vehementer angebat quod captis navigiis, quae frumenta vehebant per flumen, Isauri quidem alimentorum copiis adfluebant, ipsi vero solitarum rerum cibos iam consumendo inediae propinquantis aerumnas exitialis horrebant.
      </p>
      <p>
      Illud tamen clausos vehementer angebat quod captis navigiis, quae frumenta vehebant per flumen, Isauri quidem alimentorum copiis adfluebant, ipsi vero solitarum rerum cibos iam consumendo inediae propinquantis aerumnas exitialis horrebant.

      Cognitis enim pilatorum caesorumque funeribus nemo deinde ad has stationes appulit navem, sed ut Scironis praerupta letalia declinantes litoribus Cypriis contigui navigabant, quae Isauriae scopulis sunt controversa.

      Alii nullo quaerente vultus severitate adsimulata patrimonia sua in inmensum extollunt, cultorum ut puta feracium multiplicantes annuos fructus, quae a primo ad ultimum solem se abunde iactitant possidere, ignorantes profecto maiores suos, per quos ita magnitudo Romana porrigitur, non divitiis eluxisse sed per bella saevissima, nec opibus nec victu nec indumentorum vilitate gregariis militibus discrepantes opposita cuncta superasse virtute.
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tablist container-fluid tab-pane fade">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As all the div are 100% relative I await to not have a scrolled page.
This is not the case. Where is the issue ?
Thanks.

Comment: href="#tab-2" issue corrected

Answer (score 1):

there are so many things wrong with the example that you have posted. Allow me to list them

1. You have not included `jquery-ui` library. `jquery tabs` is a part of jquery-ui library and not jQuery
2. Your both tab headers point to same tab i.e. `<a href="#tab-1"`, where as it should be `#tab-1` for first and `#tab-2` for another
3. Your entire custom css is just too much. you don't need any of it to do what you want to.
4. you need to initialize your tabs i.e call the jQuery ui plugin on the tab container

Basically you have abused the `height` and `min-height` property. Anyhow I've simplified everything for you. Remove your entire custom css (the ones pasted here in your question) and use just these:

```
 .tablist{
        height:87%;/*fallback if calc not available*/
        height:calc(100% - 5em);
        overflow-y:auto;
 } 

.fill{
    padding: 0;
 }

.container-side {
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
 }
```

notice how `calc` property has been used in the css class `.tablist`. 
Now other than that, you must include following libraries

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

notice a new `js` library has been added after `jQuery` and `bootstrap` library 
and that is `jquery-ui.js`

also, you must initialize your tabs, so at the end of the body, you must do below

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#side').tabs();
    });
</script>
```

rest assured, it should work perfectly

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not interested to use JQuery UI. Only Bootsrap ( http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs ).

Answer (score 1):

Eureka hereafter is the solution.
To take into account of nav-tab header (42px), the size of the tab content should be recalculated. So I use :

```
.tab-content {
    overflow: auto;  
    height: calc(100vh - 42px);
    height: -webkit-calc(100vh - 42px);
    height: -moz-calc(100vh - 42px);
}
```

Otherwise all the heights are deduced from body (viewport) by inheritance:

```
.fill, .container-side {
    height: inherit;
}
```

See the complete code below:

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.fill, .container-side {
 height: inherit;
}

.tab-content {
 overflow: auto;  
 height: calc(100vh - 42px);
 height: -webkit-calc(100vh - 42px);
 height: -moz-calc(100vh - 42px);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid fill">
 <div class="row-fluid fill">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 container-side">
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
     <li class="active"><a href="#tab-1" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#tab-2" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</span></a></li>
   </ul>
   <div id="side" class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab-1" class="tablist container-fluid tab-pane fade in active">
      <p>
      Illud tamen clausos vehementer angebat quod captis navigiis, quae frumenta vehebant per flumen, Isauri quidem alimentorum copiis adfluebant, ipsi vero solitarum rerum cibos iam consumendo inediae propinquantis aerumnas exitialis horrebant.

      Cognitis enim pilatorum caesorumque funeribus nemo deinde ad has stationes appulit navem, sed ut Scironis praerupta letalia declinantes litoribus Cypriis contigui navigabant, quae Isauriae scopulis sunt controversa.
      Alii nullo quaerente vultus severitate adsimulata patrimonia sua in inmensum extollunt, cultorum ut puta feracium multiplicantes annuos fructus, quae a primo ad ultimum solem se abunde iactitant possidere, ignorantes profecto maiores suos, per quos ita magnitudo Romana porrigitur, non divitiis eluxisse sed per bella saevissima, nec opibus nec victu nec indumentorum vilitate gregariis militibus discrepantes opposita cuncta superasse virtute.

      Illud tamen te esse admonitum volo, primum ut qualis es talem te esse omnes existiment ut, quantum a rerum turpitudine abes, tantum te a verborum libertate seiungas; deinde ut ea in alterum ne dicas, quae cum tibi falso responsa sint, erubescas. Quis est enim, cui via ista non pateat, qui isti aetati atque etiam isti dignitati non possit quam velit petulanter, etiamsi sine ulla suspicione, at non sine argumento male dicere? Sed istarum partium culpa est eorum, qui te agere voluerunt; laus pudoris tui, quod ea te invitum dicere videbamus, ingenii, quod ornate politeque dixisti.

      Alii nullo quaerente vultus severitate adsimulata patrimonia sua in inmensum extollunt, cultorum ut puta feracium multiplicantes annuos fructus, quae a primo ad ultimum solem se abunde iactitant possidere, ignorantes profecto maiores suos, per quos ita magnitudo Romana porrigitur, non divitiis eluxisse sed per bella saevissima, nec opibus nec victu nec indumentorum vilitate gregariis militibus discrepantes opposita cuncta superasse virtute.

      Illud tamen te esse admonitum volo, primum ut qualis es talem te esse omnes existiment ut, quantum a rerum turpitudine abes, tantum te a verborum libertate seiungas; deinde ut ea in alterum ne dicas, quae cum tibi falso responsa sint, erubescas. Quis est enim, cui via ista non pateat, qui isti aetati atque etiam isti dignitati non possit quam velit petulanter, etiamsi sine ulla suspicione, at non sine argumento male dicere? Sed istarum partium culpa est eorum, qui te agere voluerunt; laus pudoris tui, quod ea te invitum dicere videbamus, ingenii, quod ornate politeque dixisti.
      </p>
      <p>
      Illud tamen clausos vehementer angebat quod captis navigiis, quae frumenta vehebant per flumen, Isauri quidem alimentorum copiis adfluebant, ipsi vero solitarum rerum cibos iam consumendo inediae propinquantis aerumnas exitialis horrebant.

      Cognitis enim pilatorum caesorumque funeribus nemo deinde ad has stationes appulit navem, sed ut Scironis praerupta letalia declinantes litoribus Cypriis contigui navigabant, quae Isauriae scopulis sunt controversa.
      </p>
      <p>
      Illud tamen clausos vehementer angebat quod captis navigiis, quae frumenta vehebant per flumen, Isauri quidem alimentorum copiis adfluebant, ipsi vero solitarum rerum cibos iam consumendo inediae propinquantis aerumnas exitialis horrebant.
      </p>
      <p>
      Illud tamen clausos vehementer angebat quod captis navigiis, quae frumenta vehebant per flumen, Isauri quidem alimentorum copiis adfluebant, ipsi vero solitarum rerum cibos iam consumendo inediae propinquantis aerumnas exitialis horrebant.

      Cognitis enim pilatorum caesorumque funeribus nemo deinde ad has stationes appulit navem, sed ut Scironis praerupta letalia declinantes litoribus Cypriis contigui navigabant, quae Isauriae scopulis sunt controversa.

      Alii nullo quaerente vultus severitate adsimulata patrimonia sua in inmensum extollunt, cultorum ut puta feracium multiplicantes annuos fructus, quae a primo ad ultimum solem se abunde iactitant possidere, ignorantes profecto maiores suos, per quos ita magnitudo Romana porrigitur, non divitiis eluxisse sed per bella saevissima, nec opibus nec victu nec indumentorum vilitate gregariis militibus discrepantes opposita cuncta superasse virtute.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tablist container-fluid tab-pane fade">
    ...
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
    </div>
</div>
```